# Postgresql - why cant I compound queries on schemas properly?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, navicat

Hi guys this is hopefully a simple one. I have only taken a simple SQL course and am now trying to apply it to a real postgres database. The immediate difficulty I am having is dealing with things at the schema level (multiple schemas) whereas everything I had learned only dealt with querying between multiple tables in a single schema.

I am trying to go [one step more than this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508422/how-to-find-a-table-having-a-specific-column-in-postgresql) and filter by schema, but things are behaving very weirdly to me

This is what I mean. This query returns the result I expect (and is lifted [straight from this SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508422/how-to-find-a-table-having-a-specific-column-in-postgresql)):

[image: this is fine so far but the syntax highlighting is perhaps pointing to a problem]

so given my sql training so far I figure I can take the output and further refine it.

```
select table_name
from (select table_name, table_schema from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'user_id')
where table_schema = "web_app"
```

doing this gives a very weird error:

[image]

why is it treating what is obviously a field as a column?? what is this derived_table1? (presumably its the compounded query?)

in the extremely unlikely case that it is a software issue, i am using Navicat premium 9.1.2 and connecting to amazon redshift.

Comment: `"web_app"` is an identifier. String constants need to be put into single quotes: `'web_app'`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: by god. nobody ever said double quotes were different from single quotes. that still makes no sense to me syntactically but its the right answer. thanks so much.

Comment: Well, this is how the SQL language was specified back in the 70's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Related to the colours, I suppose it is related to your tool and the keywords are coloured like this.  'table_name' seems considered as a keyword. Check the list of keywords and correct it if necessary.
- The query you have written is wrong. Please remove 'table_schema'.
- If you select from a select, then the database engine considers the list of tables returned as derived. The list is  computed at runtime and it is not easy to optimize those queries.

Comment: thanks Rudy, but the other answer was the more immediate correct answer. marked you right anyway since the guy just left it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

hi future people with the same issue, see a_horse_with_no_name's comment. thats the right answer for my issue.