# How to find all collections in a Mongo DB having keys matching some pattern?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, metadata

E.g., we can use the following query in PostgreSQL to find all the tables with columns matching some pattern:

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name ilike '%your_column_name%'
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31717112/12242023).

How can we do something similar in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Not so straightforward, but anyway you can get it [in this way](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lwN2vZjpekW)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      obj_as_arr: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      field_names: "$obj_as_arr.k",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      field_names: {
        $regex: "something"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      obj_as_arr: 0,
      field_names: 0
    }
  },
  
])
```